How do I create a Trace in Application Insights using Powershell without an Instrumentationkey?
I'm a platform platform engineer working on improving the developer experience for a number of product teams. I have refactored the Powershell code in this blogpost into a working sample that pushes information about our Github deployment workflows into Application Insights - all is good, we devs love having information at your fingertips.
However, the code relies on using InstrumentationKey and it has come to my attention that the the code I've produced relies on a legacy API which will be deprecated as of March 2025
I have failed in finding just the tiniest codesample using the OpenTelemetry distro from within Powershell - is this bleeding edge territory or am I simply not that good at googling stuff anymore?
Regards K.

Have you tried with connectionstring?

I know it's the right way to go, but I cannot wrap my head around how to implement OpenTelemetry using a Connectionstring from within a Powershell context. It's fully supported in .NET so it should be possible AFAIK
Perhaps you can help or point me in the right direction?

You need to the instrumentation key like below. Also make sure you using the most recent DLL
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$PSScriptRoot/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll")

$telemetryClient = [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient]::new()
$telemetryClient.TelemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=**************" 

$telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Tracked event")

$severityLevel = [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel]::Information
$traceData = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]]::new()
$traceData.Add("property","value")
$telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Trace", $severityLevel, $traceData)

$telemetryClient.Flush()

